# Notepad++. Как вставить строку с текстом в каждую пару строк (между строк) во всём документе?

Tags: notepad++

XXXXXX - одинаковый текст

```
строка1  
строка2  
строка3  
строка4  
строка5  
строка6
```

```
строка1  
XXXXXX  
строка2  
строка3  
XXXXXX  
строка4  
строка5  
XXXXXX  
строка6  
...
```

Ответ, спасибо @Akina
Регулярные выражения

```
Найти: (^.*\r\n)(.*\r\n)?
Заменить на: $1XXXXXX\r\n$2
```

Comment: А сами пробовали как-то? Ваш предыдущий вопрос очень похож. Что там нужно изменить, чтобы решить эту задачу? А можно ещё и справку по NPP почитать.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7pXk.png

Comment: Уважаемый @Akina , спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @rotabor , поскольку каждая чётная строка у меня начинается одинаково, решал задачу подстановкой новой строки XXXXXX в её начало, а потом переносил то, что после XXXXXX на новую строку. Теперь всё намного проще.